# Tomar foto en servicio con onPreviewFrame

Tags: android

estoy intentando tomar una foto con la camara frontal de mi dispositivo en un servicio a traves del método onPreviewFrame, pero cuando se guardan en formato .jpg, las fotos me salen corruptas y no se pueden abrir.

Es la primera vez que trabajo con la API de la camara y no se muy bien si tengo que añadir alguna configuracion mas o alguna otra cosa.

El codigo del servicio que tengo ahora mismo es el siguiente:

```
public class ServicioTextureCamara extends Service {
private final static String TAG = "CameraServiceTexture";
private Camera mCamera;
private Bitmap _currentFrame;
public static final String FACEDETECTIONTHREAD_TAG = "FaceDetectionThread_Tag";


@Override public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    new PictureThread().start();
    return START_STICKY;
}

private class PictureThread extends Thread {
    SurfaceTexture texture;
    private byte[] callbackBuffer;
    public void run() {
        mCamera = CameraHelper.getCameraInstance();

        texture = new SurfaceTexture(0);
        texture.setDefaultBufferSize(4, 4);

        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewTexture(texture);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        Camera.Size previewSize=mCamera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
        int dataBufferSize=(int)(previewSize.height*previewSize.width*
                (ImageFormat.getBitsPerPixel(mCamera.getParameters().getPreviewFormat())/8.0));
        callbackBuffer = new byte[dataBufferSize];

        mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(callbackBuffer);
        mCamera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(previewCallback);

        mCamera.startPreview();


        time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    private int mMaxCount = 100;
    private int mCount = 0;
    private long time;

    private final Camera.PreviewCallback previewCallback = new Camera.PreviewCallback() {
        @Override public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Log.i(TAG, "onPreviewFrame " + data.length + " " + (currentTime - time));
            time = currentTime;
            mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(callbackBuffer);

            File pictureFileDir = getDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            if (!pictureFileDir.exists() && !pictureFileDir.mkdirs()) {
                return;
            }
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmddhhmmss");
            String date = dateFormat.format(new Date());
            String photoFile = "PictureFront_" + "_" + date + ".jpg";
            String filename = pictureFileDir.getPath() + File.separator + photoFile;
            File mainPicture = new File(filename);

            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(mainPicture);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
                System.out.println("image saved");
            } catch (Exception error) {
                System.out.println("Image could not be saved");
            }
        }
    };

}
```

}

Alguien tiene alguna idea de que puede estar mal?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Tienes el código subido algún repo para poder probarlo?

Comment: https://github.com/kaspianh/PruebaCamaraServicio2

Comment: Perfecto hago una pruebas y te digo si veo el error

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!

Comment: No consigo que me funcione correctamente esta tarde le dedico mas rato

Comment: Ok, si necesitas algun otro dato o lo que sea me dices. De nuevo, muchisimas gracias por tu tiempo

Comment: Conseguiste hacerlo funcionar al final?

Comment: Las pruebas que hice no me funcionaron espero al fin de semana que tengo mas tiempo libre entre semana lo tengo complicado. Si encuentras la solución antes házmelo saber!

Comment: Buenas, lo estuve mirando pero sigo en el mismo punto, no consigo hacerlo funcionar. Has podido mirar algo? Gracias de nuevo!

Comment: El principal problema que tengo es que no tengo permisos de root en mi movil con lo que no puedo visualizar las imágenes que estoy guardando en memoria interna. Igualmente creo que android no permite hacer lo que propones que según veo es hacer capturas de la preview sin abrir la pantalla de la cámara es correcto?

Comment: Si, exactamente, quiero hacer capturas en un servicio sin abrir la preview ni nada